# Creating a scoring model when different variables have higher or lower as better

Tags: rating

I created a scoring model based on 4 metrics. Currently I have them weighted as such: 50%, 20%, 20% and 10%. After calculating and ranking I realized this may not work. The issue I'm facing is that for metric 1 higher is better and metrics 2-4 lower is better. Any suggestions on a better way to go about calculating this?

Comment: This doesn't need a downvote. It is a basic question on a topic that falls within our domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when creating a rating system.  Typically, the first step is to get all component variables onto the same scale.  In some contexts, there is an a-priori reason to think the scales are already commensurate, for example, if they are all likert-type items using the same responses (say, $1$ - $7$, anchored by "strongly disagree" to "strongly agree").  In other cases, you cannot assume this, so you can standardize all the variables by turning them into $z$-scores.  At that point, we run into the problem you have: the relationships are not all going in the same direction.  **You need to reverse score some of the variables so that they are all pointing in the same direction.**  How you do this depends on how your variables are constructed, but for example, if you had $1$ - $7$ likert items, you would subtract those you need to reverse score from $8$ (that turns $1$s into $7$s, e.g.).  On the other hand, if you have $z$-scores, you can multiply them by $-1$, etc.